# Referring Android vector resource in Xamarin - PCL?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm having icon resources on each platform and referring the png images using OnPlatform. It would be nice to refer vector xml like following code.

```
MapIconImage.Source = Device.OnPlatform(
            iOS: ImageSource.FromFile("Icons/location_pin.png"),
            Android: ImageSource.FromFile("location_pin.xml"),
            WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile("Icons/location_pin.png"));
```

where location_pin.xml is android vector xml

I know it's possible to use png's with corresponding dpi folders. But this one is better IMO.

Is there any way I can refer Android vector resource inside Xamarin - PCL?

Comment: Do you think it is not possible? Are you talking specifically about Maps or Image in general?

Comment: I recently answered a question about vector source for radio buttons, so it is possible to assign vector xml for image in Android. You might need custom renderer (or not :-) )

Comment: @YuriS It has nothing to do with maps. Just a icon for imagebutton.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple button custom renderer.

Page:

```
public class VectorImageSourceAndroidPage : ContentPage
{
    public VectorImageSourceAndroidPage()
    {

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new VectorImageButton() {
                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    WidthRequest=70,
                    HeightRequest=70,
                    BackgroundColor=Color.Blue,

                     Source = Device.OnPlatform(
                        iOS: "",
                        Android: "woman",
                        WinPhone: "")
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class VectorImageButton : Button
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VectorImageButton), typeof(VectorImageRenderer))]
namespace ButtonRendererDemo.Droid
{
    public class VectorImageRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var button = (VectorImageButton)e.NewElement;
                var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(button.Source).GetValue(null);

                Control.Background = Context.GetDrawable(resourceId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resource in drawable folder:

woman.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval"
            android:id="@+id/shapeBg">
      <solid android:color="#ff69b4"/>
      <size android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/woman_path"/>
</layer-list>
```

woman_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="70dp"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="70"
    android:viewportHeight="70">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:pathData="M43 45l-6 0 0 -5c6,-1 11,-6 11,-13 0,-7 -6,-13 -13,-13 -7,0 -13,6 -13,13 0,7
5,12 11,13l0 5 -6 0c-2,0 -2,3 0,3l6 0 0 6c0,2 4,2 4,0l0 -6 6 0c2,0 2,-3
0,-3zm-18 -18c0,-5 5,-10 10,-10 5,0 10,5 10,10 0,5 -5,10 -10,10 -5,0 -10,-5
-10,-10z" />
</vector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for something similar and came to a solution using a platform specific ImageRenderer. Since the ImageRenderer can be made specific for Android you can use their vector drawables. For this in your shared forms project you first create:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class VectorImage : Image
    {
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the corresponding xaml:

```
<myApp:VectorImage ImageSource="location_pin" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" />
```

Then add in your android project the specific (vector) ImageRenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VectorImage), typeof(VectorImageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class VectorImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        protected override bool DrawChild(Canvas canvas, global::Android.Views.View child, long drawingTime)
        {
            var imageSource = ((VectorImage) Element).ImageSource;
            var vectorDrawable = Context.Resources.GetDrawable(imageSource);
            vectorDrawable.SetBounds(0, 0, Width, Height);
            vectorDrawable.Draw(canvas);
            return base.DrawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Should be good to go.